# Extract data from JSON file in R

Tags: r, json, subset, nested-lists

I have a .json file that contains corresponding pairs of **IDs** and **category names**. How can I extract them?

I converted the file:

```
categories <- fromJSON("CA_category_id.json")
```

and got a nested list as a result.

I need:

```
categories[["items"]]["id"]
```

and

```
categories[["items"]][["snippet"]][["title"]]
```

combined in one table. Like this:

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Film & Animation |
| 2 | Autos & Vehicles |
| 10 | Music |
| 15 | Pets & Animals |
| ... | ... |

You can find the initial .json file [here](https://www.kaggle.com/kronoc/starter-trending-youtube-video). It is called *CA_category_id.json*.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What you showed us were two one-line expressions.  What do you find to be wrong with them?

Comment: I need a table that would contain pairs of IDs and category names:

1 - Film & Animation;
2 - Autos & Vehicles;
10 - Music;
15 - Pets & Animals etc.

Right now I am only able to get two separate lists: one with IDs and one with category names, but not two of them combined correspondingly.

Comment: I added a desired output to make my question more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way is to go item by item. Working code below:

```
library(rjson)
library(data.table)
categories <- fromJSON(file="CA_category_id.json")
table <- NULL
for (index in seq_along(categories$items) ) {
  table <- rbind(table,data.table(id=categories[["items"]][[index]][["id"]],title=categories[["items"]][[index]][["snippet"]][["title"]]))
}
table
```

Comment: Thank you, Miguel! That's what I wanted.

Why do you use data.table() here?

Comment: One little note:  to save a bit of typing, you can write `categories[["items"]][[index]][["snippet"]][["title"]]` as `categories[[c("items", index, "snippet", "title")]]`, or even `v <- c("items", " ", "snippet", "title"); v[2] <- index; categories[[v]]`.

Comment: You are welcome Alina!  -  I use data.table all the time because is powerful, faster and I prefer it over the typical R dataframes. A matter of taste I anyway :) Have a nice day, good luck with your project